# How to assign "IDs" to global variables in a definition

Tags: python, variables, global-variables

Okay, I have a function which is basically a grouping up global variables that get updated by other definitions.

What I want to do is be able to re-use this definition to add CTRLS to other layouts later on, but I run into the issue of the same variable names being used. Is there a way to add an attribute per variable? or an ID in python so that when the function is run a second time the variables have an identifer?

```
def createDomeLightCTRLS(self,lightName,parentFrame):

    lightShape = mel.listRelatives(lightName,shapes=True)   

    self.LD3 = mel.rowLayout(parent = parentFrame, numberOfColumns = 7, cat = [(1,'left',10)])

    self.LD3_Spherical = mel.checkBox(str(lightName[0]) + '_spherical', label = 'Dome Spherical' , value = False )     
    mel.separator(hr = False, width = 10, height = 20, style = 'out')                                
    self.LD3_SubDivs = mel.intSliderGrp(str(lightName[0]) + '_subdivs', label = 'SubDivs', min = 1, max = 100, field = True, value = 8, cw = [(1,45),(2,45),(3,75)])
    mel.separator(hr = False, width = 10, height = 20, style = 'out')                                        
    self.LD3_rayDistCheck = mel.checkBox(str(lightName[0]) + '_rayDistCheck', label = 'Use Distance', value = False)             
    mel.separator(hr = False, width = 10, height = 20, style = 'out')          
    self.LD3_rayDist = mel.floatSliderGrp(str(lightName[0]) + '_rayDist', label = 'Distance', pre = 3, enable = False, field = True, value = False, min = 1, max = 1000000000, cw = [(1,45),(2,85),(3,85)] )

    mel.setParent('..') # LD3 ( LD3 rowLayout) CLOSED

    self.LD4 = mel.rowLayout(parent = parentFrame, numberOfColumns = 7, cat = [(1,'left',10)])

    self.LD4_shadowBias = mel.floatFieldGrp( annotation = "Dome Light Light Shadow Bias: Distance of Shadows from Objects, (Default Should Be Enough)", label = 'Shadow Bias', numberOfFields = 1, precision = 3, value1 = .020, columnWidth = [(1,65),(2,75)], enable = True)
    mel.separator(hr = False, width = 10, height = 20, style = 'out')                                
    self.LD4_shadowColor = mel.colorSliderGrp( annotation = "Dome Light Shadow Color", label='Shadow Color', columnWidth = [( 1,75 ),( 2,75 ),( 3,115 )], rgb=( 0, 0, 0 ), enable = True)               

    mel.setParent('..') # LD4 ( LD4 rowLayout) CLOSED

    self.LD5 = mel.rowLayout(parent = parentFrame, numberOfColumns = 5, columnAttach=[(1,'left',10)])        

    self.LD5_UseHDRI = mel.checkBox(str(lightName[0]) + '_useHDRI', annotation = "On/Off Use Dome Texture, Overrides Dome Light Color", label='Use HDRI', v=False)        
    mel.separator(hr = False, width = 10, height = 20, style = 'out')                
    self.LD5_TexAdaptive = mel.checkBox(str(lightName[0]) + '_texAdaptive', annotation = "On/Off Explict Texture Resoltion, Overrides input File Resolution", label='Texture Adaptive', enable = False, v=False)        
    mel.separator(hr = False, width = 10, height = 20, style = 'out')                
    self.LD5_TexRes = mel.floatSliderGrp(str(lightName[0]) + '_texRes', annotation = "Texture Resolution, if Texture Adaptive is Enabled", 
                                         columnAttach = [(2,'both',5)], 
                                         columnWidth = [(1,95),(2,75),(3,125)], 
                                         enable = False, 
                                         label='Texture Resolution', 
                                         field=True, 
                                         minValue=128, 
                                         maxValue=4096, 
                                         step = 128, 
                                         fieldMinValue=128, 
                                         fieldMaxValue=4096, 
                                         value=128
                                         )

    mel.setParent('..') # LD5 ( LD5 rowLayout) CLOSED

    self.LD6 = mel.rowLayout(parent = parentFrame, numberOfColumns = 4, columnWidth=[(1,300)],columnAttach=[(1,'both',10)])  

    self.LD6_UseRGB = mel.checkBox(str(lightName[0]) + '_useRGB', annotation = "Use Color Slider to Determine Dome Light Color", label='Use RGB Dome Color', enable = False, v=False)
    self.LD6_UseHDRIFile = mel.checkBox (str(lightName[0]) + '_useHDRIFile', annotation = "Use HDRI to Determine Dome Light Color", label='Use HDRI File', enable = False, v=False)

    mel.setParent('..') # LD6 (LD6 rowLayout) CLOSED 

    self.LD7 = mel.rowLayout(parent = parentFrame, 
    numberOfColumns = 4,
    columnWidth=[(1,300)],
    columnAttach=[(1,'both',10),(2,'both',0),(3,'both',5),(4,'both',5)])

    self.LD7_DomeColor = mel.colorSliderGrp(str(lightName[0]) + '_domeColor', annotation = "Dome Light Color", 
                                                  label='Dome Color', 
                                                  enable = False, 
                                                  columnAttach = [(1,'both',0), (2,'both',5), (3,'left',0), (4,'both',0)], 
                                                  columnWidth = [( 1,55 ),( 2,60 ),( 3,10 ),(4,0)], 
                                                  rgb=( 1, 1, 1 )
                                                  )

    self.LD7_HDRITextName = mel.text(str(lightName[0]) + '_HDRITextName', annotation = "Search for HDRI (jpg,HDR) to Use in Dome Light", label = 'HDRI File Name', enable = False)
    self.LD7_HDRITextField = mel.textField(str(lightName[0]) + '_HDRITextField', text = '', width = 150, enable = False )
    self.LD7_HDRIButton = mel.symbolButton (str(lightName[0]) + '_HDRISymbolButton', image='openScript.png',enable = False)

    mel.setParent('..') # (LD7 (LD7 rowLayout) CLOSE                       

    #options

    self.LD8_optionFrame = mel.frameLayout(str(lightName[0]) + '_optionFrame',parent = parentFrame, label = 'Options', labelVisible = True, cl = True, cll = True )

    self.LD8 = mel.rowLayout(parent = self.LD8_optionFrame,numberOfColumns = 9, cat = [(1,'left',10)])

    self.LD8_invisible = mel.checkBox(str(lightName[0]) + '_invisible',label = 'Invisible', value = False)         
    mel.separator(hr = False, width = 10, height = 20, style = 'out')                                        
    self.LD8_irradianceMap = mel.checkBox(str(lightName[0]) + '_storeIrradiance',label = 'Store with Irradiance', value = False)
    mel.separator(hr = False, width = 10, height = 20, style = 'out')                                                
    self.LD8_diffuse = mel.checkBox(str(lightName[0]) + '_diffuse',label = 'Diffuse', value = True)
    mel.separator(hr = False, width = 10, height = 20, style = 'out')                                
    self.LD8_specular = mel.checkBox(str(lightName[0]) + '_specular',label = 'Specular', value = True)
    mel.separator(hr = False, width = 10, height = 20, style = 'out')                                
    self.LD8_reflection = mel.checkBox(str(lightName[0]) + '_reflection',label = 'Reflection', value = True)

    mel.setParent('..') # (LD8 (LD8 rowLayout) CLOSE

    mel.setParent('..') # LR8_optionFrame (LR8_optionFrame frameLayout) CLOSED
```

Thank you so much!
let me know if there's an easier or better way to achieve this, as I am definitely new to python.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking about. The only "global" variable in your code is `mel`, which I'm guessing is a module, and not what you're talking about. If you want to attach some extra data to your `LDx_whatever` member variables, perhaps you should use some other data structure (like nested lists or dictionaries), rather than giving them unique variable names.

Comment: Don't get the poing. And: `If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.` Read [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length), python style guide. Reading some decent coding standatrds, such as [google's ones](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html) should also be benefical

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: This code does not work. I would have deleting it except I think it helps point out what the questioner is asking!**

> Dope -- should have tested it in the interpreter!

You can "add variables" to any object in python.

```
a = range(10)
a.ID = 'MY ID'
```

I'm not very clear what you are asking!

Comment: This isn't true for any object, only for some types. Many builtin types (such as `list`, `dict`, `tuple`, and the various number types) don't allow you to set arbitrary attributes. `[].foo = "bar"` => `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'foo'`. Custom classes do allow it by default (though you can prevent it by giving them a `__slots__` class variable with no `__dict__`). Your example is a case where it won't work (in either Python 2 or Python 3).